# What hardware do I REALLY need?

Tags: server, web-server

At the Moment, I have a Fujistu RX300 S6 with 2 hexa-core Xeon's with HyperThreading (24 threads) at 2.6 GHz, 128 GB DDR3 ECC, 200 GB SSD an 4 TB HDD in my basement, but the electricity alone cost me 70€ a month.
I want to cut cost and the server is mostly idleing around 3-4 % on CPU and 10-15 % on RAM.

My idea was to get a cheap VPS L from Contabo with 8 Cores, 30 GB RAM, 200 GB NVMe and a 400 mbit up&down connection for 15€ a month.

My friend (who is using the server at 99% of the time) says, it is **WAY** too weak for what we do with it.

The current server runs Debian 11 with the following services:

- NextCloud
- FiveM (~ 5-10 Players at a time)
- CloudNet Minecraft network (~ 3-4 Players due to it not being finished)
- MySQL database
- Docker

Docker containers:

- OpenProject
- NginX
- AzuraCast
- Grafana
- UptimeKuma

For the Nextcloud, I have a NasBox 5 G3 from Terra with >7 TB of storage
(drives are in RAID5)

Is the VPS really **THAT** underpowered for the things i have listed?

Comment: How many Ghz is provided with the 8 core CPU?

Answer (score 0):

It is not too weak when  talking about processing power. Where is may be too weak is in RAM and storage. I would reccomend 64GB of RAM and maybe half a terabyte of local NVMe storage. If you want to expand later, maybe it is also a good idea to go with a 12core processor.